# WPF Add more interaction to listview items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I am binding my listview to a viewmodel using Caliburn. My view's code is the following:

```
<ListView  x:Name="ListView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectsPMod}" Margin="110,0,110,131" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Height="111" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="OpenProjectShell">
                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=ListView, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                </cal:ActionMessage>
            </interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ContentControl  Content="{StaticResource  Appbar_Suitcase}" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Right now each item in every row just displays its name and a briefcase icon. If I wanted to add an "Edit"further down that row, where if you clicked on it something happened (perhaps a popup appears), how would I do it?

Comment: How would you do what? Please narrow down your question.

Comment: You can change the `ItemTemplate` to be however complex you need it to be, think Grids, ItemsControls, TabControls (please don't use tab controls).  You can add a button to the template easily, and just bind its `Command` property to an `ICommand` on your view model to get it to run that behavior.

Comment: @mm8 With either a button that binds to a Command, or a hyperlink that would map to something similar.

Comment: @Iason: See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an ordinary `Button` look like a link using a template. Just add a `Button` to your `StackPanel` and bind it to a command:

```
<ListView  x:Name="ListView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectsPMod}" Margin="110,0,110,131" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Height="111" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="OpenProjectShell">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=ListView, Path=SelectedItem}" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentControl  Content="{StaticResource  Appbar_Suitcase}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"/>

                <Button Margin="0 10 0 0" Content="Link" Cursor="Hand" Command="{Binding YourCommand}">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You can control the position of the `Button` within the `StackPanel` using its `Margin` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "How to add an edit button for each row?" then you simply need to add a button in the ItemTemplate:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentControl  Content="{StaticResource  Appbar_Suitcase}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <!-- Edit button -->
                    <Button Command="{Binding EditCommandOnViewModel}" Content="Edit" />
                </StackPanel>

                <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for. How can we put that button further down that row, so as not to be so close to the name? And make it look more like a hyperlink rather than a plain button?